# Know resulting image size before performing a resize in Imageresizer

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

I need to know the destination size of an image before [imageresizer](http://imageresizing.net/) actually perform the re-size. And I don't want to open the image file.

I have the original image size and the imageresizer parameters.

I want to write an img tag this way:

```
<img src="/files/rb45_45667.jpg?height=150&quality=90" width="XXX" height="YYY">
```

I tried with [ImageState](http://documentation.imageresizing.net/docu/ImageResizer.Resizing/ImageState.htm)

```
var imagestate = new ImageState(new ResizeSettings("height=150;quality=90"), new Size(1000,500), true);
imagestate.destSize = PolygonMath.RoundPoints(imagestate.layout.GetBoundingBox().Size);
```

but this wont work because i think I should perform all the [ImageBuilder](http://documentation.imageresizing.net/docu/ImageResizer/ImageBuilder.htm) Layout protected methods:

```
protected override RequestedAction Layout(ImageState s) {
    if (base.Layout(s) == RequestedAction.Cancel) return RequestedAction.Cancel;
    FlipExistingPoints(s); //Not implemented
    LayoutImage(s);
    PostLayoutImage(s);
    LayoutPadding(s);
    PostLayoutPadding(s);
    LayoutBorder(s);
    PostLayoutBorder(s);
    LayoutEffects(s);
    PostLayoutEffects(s);
    LayoutMargin(s);
    PostLayoutMargin(s);
    LayoutRotate(s);
    PostLayoutRotate(s);
    LayoutNormalize(s);
    PostLayoutNormalize(s);
    LayoutRound(s);
    PostLayoutRound(s);
    EndLayout(s);
    return RequestedAction.None;
}
```

But this is impossible without opening the image file...

In the [ImageState](http://documentation.imageresizing.net/docu/ImageResizer.Resizing/ImageState.htm) documentation they says:

> Encapsulates the state of an image being resized. Can be used to simulate a resize as well as actually perform one.

But i don't find a way how do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a simple way to do it.

I don't know if it is the right way to do it but it works:

```
ImageBuilder.Current.GetFinalSize(ImageSize, new ResizeSettings(parameters));
```